# JavaScript. Removing duplicate elements in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates

I am trying to eliminate duplicate elements in a array, the thing is that my array has the following:

```
var array=[];
array[0]["firstColumn"]="Peter";
array[0]["SecondColumn"]=[];
array[1]["firstColumn"]="Peter";
array[1]["SecondColumn"]=[];
```

I tried something like this but it will only eliminate the array if in each value it has only a string

```
$.each($scope.array, function(i, el){
    if($.inArray(el.Adultos, uniqueNames) === -1) uniqueNames.push(el);
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove Duplicates from JavaScript Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array)

Comment: You should search before you ask a question. Chances are there are answers already out there, especially for a question like this.

Comment: I got it from there, but the array from there is different from my one, the one there is like this var names = ["Mike","Matt","Nancy","Adam","Jenny","Nancy","Carl"];

Comment: The array is made of key value

Comment: Can you provide your array?

Comment: You array does not work in a javascript emulator to start with.

Comment: In the console.log I have: Array [ Array[0], Array[0], Array[0] ] and each one is: Age:Array[0],Adult:"2",Amount:"2"

Comment: An array of key values is an array of objects and in javascript looks like this `[{"firstColumn": "Peter", "SecondColumn" : [] }, {"firstColumn": "Peter", "SecondColumn" : [] }]` which would make your code look like this `array[0] = {"firstColumn": "Peter", "SecondColumn" : [] };  array[1] = {"firstColumn": "Peter", "SecondColumn" : [] }`

Comment: Your console log means your data is an array of arrays and looks like this `[ [{ Age:Array[0], Adult:"2", Amount:"2"}], [{ Age:Array[0], Adult:"2", Amount:"2"}], [{ Age:Array[0], Adult:"2", Amount:"2"}] ] `. Where is your data coming from, can you format it, and whats your end goal?